# What is the equivalent of React router's useHistory hook in Reach router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby, reach-router

I am in a gatsby project and I am trying to add query strings using 'qs' library and in the docs mentioned using:

```
const history = useHistory()
```

Then
 `history.push(myStringParameter)`

useHistory doesn't exist in Gatsby(Reach router) so what can I use instead?

Is there an equivalent in reach router? I have only really ever used React router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [`useNavigate`](https://reach.tech/router/api/useNavigate) from `@reach/router`

> If you need to navigate programmatically (like after a form submits), this hook gives you an API to do so with a signature like this: